# How to show that every circle through the points $(2, 0)$ and $(-2, 0)$ is orthogonal to the circle $x^2 + y^2 - 5x + 4 = 0$

Tags: calculus, geometry

Two intersecting circles are said to be orthogonal to each other, if the tangents to the two circles at any point of intersection, are perpendicular to each other. Show that every circle through the points $(2,0)$ and $(-2, 0)$ is orthogonal to the circle $x^2 + y^2 - 5x + 4 = 0$.

I found this question on a practrice book im using to prepare for the math olympiad in my country.

im not familiar with 2 variable functions which is why i wanted to find simpler method to find the answer.

forgive my bad english as english isnt my first language.

Comment: One possible hint: Circles $C_1(O_1, r_1)$ and $C_2(O_2, r_2)$ are orthogonal if and only if $r_1^2+r_2^2=O_1O_2^2$. (Draw the radii to the intersection point, conclude that they are perpendicular to each other, use Pythagoras' theorem.) Now you can try to apply this statement to this problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Answer (score 1):

My First Post!

Since the circle passes through $(-2, 0)$ and $(2,0)$, the center must lie on the perpendicular bisector, i.e $x = 0$. Therefore any circle passing through these points must be of the form, $x^2 + (y-k)^2 = (k^2 + 4)$.

Note that if the tangents at the intersection points are perpendicular, then the tangents must pass through the centers of these circles. Let $O_1, O_2$ be the centers and $A,B$ be the points of intersection. We need $O_1A$ and $O_2A$ to be tangent to circles centered at $O_2, O_1$ respectively. Then we require $O_1A \perp O_2A$. The distance between the centers of the circles is $O_1O_2 = k^2 + 2.5^2$. $O_1A^2 = k^2 + 4$ and $O_2B^2 = 1.5^2$. By converse of pythagorean theorem, since $O_1O_2^2 = O_1A^2 + O_1B^2$, $O_1A \perp O_2A$. Symmetrically for $B$.